# Ребят помогите как сделать вот такое окно, с помощью QGridLayout()?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlayout, qgridlayout

Хочу чтобы при растяжение окна верхняя зеленая бровь растягивалась только по горизонтали, не могу разобраться с `qsizepolicy`.

[image: Хочу вот такое окно]

---

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
        self.setupUI()
    
        self.setForm()
    
    def setupUI(self):  # Форма главного окна
        self.move(650, 250)  # Отступы
        self.setWindowTitle('КБЖУ')  # Название программы
        self.heading = QLabel('Звголовок', self)  # Бровь программы
        self.heading.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(255, 126, 14);')  # Цыет фона брови
    
        self.name = QLabel('Введите имя:', self)
    
        self.nameInput = QLineEdit(self)  # Ввод имени
    
        self.btn_ok = QPushButton('Далее', self)
    
    
    def setForm(self):
        grid = QGridLayout()  # Создаем Макет сетки
        #  добавляем в макет наши виджеты
        grid.addWidget(self.heading, 0, 0, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.name, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.nameInput, 2, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.btn_ok, 3, 3)
        grid.setSpacing(0)  # Отступы между элементами
        grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)  # Отступы от краев программы
        self.setLayout(grid)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QGridLayout::**setRowStretch**(int **row**, int **stretch**)
>
> Устанавливает коэффициент растяжения строки для растяжения.
> Первая строка - это номер 0.
>
> Коэффициент растяжения относится к другим строкам в этой сетке.
> Ряды с более высоким коэффициентом растяжения занимают больше доступного места.
>
> Коэффициент растяжения по умолчанию равен 0. Если коэффициент растяжения равен 0
> и никакая другая строка в этой таблице не может расти вообще,
> строка все равно может расти.

```
  layout.setRowStretch(0, 0)
  layout.setRowStretch(1, 1)
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUI()
        self.setForm()

    def setupUI(self):                            # Форма главного окна
        self.move(650, 250)                       # Отступы
        self.setWindowTitle('КБЖУ')               # Название программы
        self.heading = QLabel('Звголовок', self)  # Бровь программы
        self.heading.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(255, 126, 14);')  
        
        self.name = QLabel('Введите имя:', self)
        self.nameInput = QLineEdit(self)          # Ввод имени
        
        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.flayout = QFormLayout(self.frame)
        self.flayout.addRow(self.name, self.nameInput)
        
        self.btn_ok = QPushButton('Далее', self)

    def setForm(self):
        grid = QGridLayout(self)  
        grid.addWidget(self.heading, 0, 0, 1, 4)
        grid.addWidget(self.frame, 2, 1, 2, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.btn_ok, 4, 3)
        grid.setSpacing(0)                   # Отступы между элементами
        grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)  # Отступы от краев программы
        
        grid.setRowStretch(0, 0)
        grid.setRowStretch(1, 1)
        grid.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        grid.setRowStretch(3, 1)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUI()
        self.setForm()

    def setupUI(self):                            
        self.move(650, 250)                       
        self.setWindowTitle('КБЖУ')               
        self.heading = QLabel('<h2>Звголовок</h2>', self)                 # +++
        self.heading.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)                         # +++
        self.heading.setMinimumHeight(40)                                 # +++
        self.heading.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(255, 126, 14);')  
        
        self.name = QLabel('Введите имя:', self)
        self.nameInput = QLineEdit(self)          
        
        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.flayout = QFormLayout(self.frame)
        self.flayout.addRow(self.name, self.nameInput)
        
        self.btn_ok = QPushButton('Далее', self)

    def setForm(self):
        grid = QGridLayout(self)  
        grid.addWidget(self.heading, 0, 0, 1, 4)
        grid.addWidget(self.frame, 2, 1, 2, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.btn_ok, 4, 3)
        grid.setSpacing(0)                   
        grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)  
        
        grid.setRowStretch(0, 0)
        grid.setRowStretch(1, 1)
        grid.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        grid.setRowStretch(3, 1)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_()) 
    
    
    
    

import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUI()
        self.setForm()

    def setupUI(self):                            # Форма главного окна
        self.move(650, 250)                       # Отступы
        self.setWindowTitle('КБЖУ')               # Название программы
        self.heading = QLabel('Звголовок', self)  # Бровь программы
        self.heading.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(255, 126, 14);')  
        
        self.name = QLabel('Введите имя:', self)
        self.nameInput = QLineEdit(self)          # Ввод имени
        
        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.flayout = QFormLayout(self.frame)
        self.flayout.addRow(self.name, self.nameInput)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(77, 126, 77);')
        
        self.btn_ok = QPushButton('Далее', self)
        self.frame2 = QFrame()
        self.hlayout = QVBoxLayout(self.frame2)
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.btn_ok)

    def setForm(self):
        grid = QGridLayout(self)  
        grid.addWidget(self.heading, 0, 0, 1, 4)
        grid.setRowStretch(1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.frame, 2, 1, 1, 2)
        grid.setRowStretch(3, 1)
#        grid.addWidget(self.btn_ok, 4, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.frame2, 4, 3)
        
        
        grid.setSpacing(0)                   # Отступы между элементами
        grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 10)  # Отступы от краев программы
        
        grid.setRowStretch(0, 0)
        grid.setRowStretch(1, 1)
        grid.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        grid.setRowStretch(3, 1)
        grid.setRowStretch(4, 0)
#        grid.setRowStretch(5, 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста а как сделать чтобы ввод имени  и само поле имени были всегда по центру?

Comment: @Tesla я добавил обновление в свой ответ. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour . Также не забудьте принять решение по предыдущему вашему вопросу.

Comment: Спасибо, все круто, подскажите пожалуйста последний вопрос, я хочу чтобы оранжевый заголовок бы толще, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: @Tesla я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте. Пожалуйста, прочитайте внимательно мой первый комментарий.

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: А можно еще спросить, ты с помощью QFrame() QFormLayout объединил name и nameInput, а можно ли еще туда добавить btn_ok, чтобы кнопка далее была на одном уровне с ними?

Comment: @Tesla все можно, почитайте https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qformlayout.html , если что-то не поймете - зададите новый вопрос.